# Separating a column by using regex expressions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
tibble(x = c("asdh.1", "asdh.1.1", "cccc.1.1", "asdh.1.2", "cccc.1.2", "asdh.1.11", "cccc.1.11"))
# A tibble: 7 x 1
  x        
  <chr>    
1 asdh.1   
2 asdh.1.1 
3 cccc.1.1 
4 asdh.1.2 
5 cccc.1.2 
6 asdh.1.11
7 cccc.1.11
```

Now I would like to split the column `x` into 2 columns such that the second column only contains the digits after the last dot, and the first column everything before the last dot. I tried messing around with regex but did not accomplish the desired outcome. The closest I got might be `%>% separate(col=x, into=c("y", "numbers"), sep="(.*)\\.([1-9]{1,2}$)")` but that gives only two empty columns.

Comment: Did you meant `df1 %>% separate(col = x, into = c("y", "numbers"), sep = "\\.(?=\\d+$)", convert = TRUE)` or is it `df1 %>% separate(col = x, into = c("y", "numbers"), sep = "(?<=\\d)\\.(?=\\d*$)", convert = TRUE)`

Comment: first one :) I'd happy to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify a regex lookaround in `separate` to match the `.` (`.` is a metacharacter that matches any character - so we escape `\\`) followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, col = x, into = c("y", "numbers"), 
       sep = "\\.(?=\\d+$)", convert = TRUE)
```